# Probability Question on Blackjack - Looking for verification

Tags: probability

In the game of Blackjack, a basic strategy player will end up with a hand consisting of 3 or more cards about 51% of the time. That being said, what is the formula for finding the probability of the player getting a hand consisting of 3 or more cards and the first 3 cards being Red?

I believe this should be:

(Probability of getting a 3 or more card hand)(Prob of getting 3 consectutive Red cards)

(.51)*((26/52)(25/51)(24/50))

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes I think you are correct, but it's on the assumption that you are playing the game with one set of cards.

Comment: You need to specify what you mean by "basic strategy."  In any event, I suspect the calculation is subtler, because requiring that the cards be the same color changes the odds of hitting various counts.

Comment: @BarryCipra: I shared the same concern, but on second thoughts, I think the statement "a basic strategy player will end up with a hand consisting of 3 or more cards about 51% of the time" already reflects the probability with all situations accounted for. That is, by using this strategy to deal with every possible situation (such as a different card shown by the dealer, different first and second cards combinations), the player will end up with 3 or more cards for 51% of all these combinations. Not sure if this interpretation is right?

Comment: @LaBird, consider a stripped-down toy model of Blackjack played with just six cards:  the Ace, two, and three of Hearts and Spades (with Aces counting only as $1$).  Suppose the "basic strategy" is to "stand" on any count greater than $2$, in which case you only wind up with three cards if you start with the pair of Aces.  This happens with probability $1/15$, which plays the role of the OP's $51\%$.  The OP's approach to the probability of winding up with three cards all red gives $(1/15)(3/6)(2/5)(1/4)=1/300$.  But the actual probability is clearly $0$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: You are right. I think the multiplication gives $1/300$ instead of $1/60$, but your explanation is justified and is very clear!

Comment: @LaBird, thanks.  (I corrected the $1/60$ to $1/300$ almost immediately.  You must have caught the page before I made the change.)

Comment: Incidentally, when I considered some slightly less stripped-down models, the OP's approach *did* produce the correct result.